# Interfaces for entities?

Tags: entities, coding-standards

The Drupal [code standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/object-oriented-code#interfaces) explains that I should use interfaces. And I always did that. But I never understood why.

> because it allows more flexibility in extending code later

Why does an interface allow more flexibility in extending the code later?

> A separate interface definition also neatly centralizes documentation making it easier to read.

How does an interface definition centralize documentation?

I also don't understand this part. What methods should I split off?

> If there is even a remote possibility of a class being swapped out for another implementation at some point in the future, split the method definitions off into a formal Interface.

> A class that is intended to be extended must always provide an Interface that other classes can implement rather than forcing them to extend the base class.

And why is it bad to extend the whole class?

Comment: This is a general OOP question and nothing specific to Drupal

Comment: I think this is a legitimate line of inquiry ("why did Drupal shift to OOP?"), but there are too many questions in one post to allow for a quality answer.

Comment: You should google for *composition vs. inheritance*, there is a lot of literature on this topic.

Comment: This question would be better received on the Drupal forums, which are better for discussion. Drupal Answers here is for direct QA questions on Drupal only.

Comment: Definitely an interesting thing to discuss @PatrickKenny, but not here - it’s not something that could have a correct answer

Comment: @PatrickKenny The question doesn't ask why Drupal shifted to OOP; it asks different questions about OOP, which (for that reason) aren't Drupal-related. They could even be asked for any language that supports the OOP paradigm, with the exception of a question, if there isn't a tool for that language that is able to parse a documentation comment containing `@{inheritdoc}`.